# Create ESLint configuration that works for both Vue 2 and Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, eslint, eslintrc

I need to some how create an ESLint configuration that works for both Vue 2 and Vue 3, to be able to use it across multiple projects (by installing it as an NPM package).

I tried to use vue-demi to detect the Vue version and then switch things out in the .eslintrc file, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this? Would really appreciate the help!

Comment: You can just read vue version from package.json and conditionally add plugins to `extends` section in eslint config

Comment: @EstusFlask How do I read the Vue version?

Comment: Something like `let package = require('./package.json'); let vueVer = Object.entries(package.dependencies).find(([k]) => k === 'vue')[1]; let isVue2 = semver.satisfies('2', vueVer)`. Where semver is semver package or any other semver parser

Answer (score 0):

You can use different majors of the package for different majors of Vue. Let's say your package is `awesome-eslint-plugin`.

The project's `.eslintrc.yml` would look like this, regardless of Vue version:

```yaml
root: true
extends:
 - 'plugin:awesome-eslint-plugin'
```

In Vue2 projects install `awesome-eslint-plugin@^2`.
In Vue3 projects install `awesome-eslint-plugin@^3`.

Or `@latest` and `@next`.